# .net core identity 2.1 role authorize not working

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-identity

I've implemented role based auth several times pre 2.1. Followed the steps to scaffold the new 2.1 identities.

I extended the IdentityUser model to add additional fields, login works fine, new fields are present.

startup.cs configure services contains

```
         services.AddDefaultIdentity<AppUser>()
            .AddRoles<IdentityRole>()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
```

I seeded the roles

```
         IdentityRole role = new IdentityRole();
         role.Name = "Administrator";
         IdentityResult roleResult = roleManager.
         CreateAsync(role).Result;
```

Then created a user and added to the role

```
        AppUser user = new AppUser();
        user.UserName = "Admin";
        user.Email = "admin@admin.com";
        user.Name = "Administrator";
        user.LockoutEnabled = false;
        user.EmailConfirmed = true;

        IdentityResult result = userManager.CreateAsync(user, "password").Result;

        if (result.Succeeded)
        {
            userManager.AddToRoleAsync(user, "Administrator").Wait();
        }
```

Everything succeeded, and the database looks fine (AspNetUserRoles has links)

However, decorating a controller with a role will always return not authorized

```
       [Authorize(Roles = "Administrator")]
```

But, a simple login check with `[Authorize]` (no role) will work.

How might I fix this/what is the easiest way to incorporate the source code so I can step through/debug the `[Authorize]` tags?

Comment: To debug maybe you can use the [Authorize] and add somewhere in the action method: var claims = User.Claims; So you can see if the claims are really there

Comment: Do you have cookies configured?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

#### How to fix

> However, decorating a controller with a role will always return not authorized
>
> ```
>   [Authorize(Roles = "Administrator")]
> ```

It's a known bug in the version of `2.1` . See [issue](https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/issues/1813) here .

I follow the advice [of using the old api suggested by HaoK and C-BERBER](https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/issues/1813#issuecomment-413928717) , and it now works flawlessly .

Here's my `DbContext`:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<AppUser,IdentityRole,string>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }
}
```

Configure the identity using the old-style api :

```
services.AddIdentity<AppUser, IdentityRole>()
        .AddRoleManager<RoleManager<IdentityRole>>()
        .AddDefaultUI()
        .AddDefaultTokenProviders()
        .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
```

Lastly , **logout and re-signin** , it will work as expected now .

#### How to Debug source code

I guess you won't want to debug the `AuthorizeAttribe` itself , since it is processed at compile-time . If you mean to debug the `AuthorizeFilter` , you can follow the steps as below :

click `Tools` -> `Options` -> `Debugging`

1. within `General` , **unselect** the `Enable Just My Code` in Visual Studio
2. select `Enable Source Link Support`
3. within `Symbols` , make sure that the **Microsoft Symbol Servers** is selected

And you can debug the source code now . However , due to the way that filter works , you need set a breakpoint before MVC . I just set a dummy middleware that will take place before the MVC router handler :

[image]

The screenshot of debugging `AuthorizeFiler` :

[image]

Answer (score 10):

In my case of ASP.NET Core 3 (preview) + Angular, solution was in **AddAuthentication**

```
services.AddDefaultIdentity<ApplicationUser>()
    .AddRoles<IdentityRole>()
    .AddRoleManager<RoleManager<IdentityRole>>()
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();

services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme;
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme;
    options.DefaultSignInScheme = IdentityConstants.ExternalScheme;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I added role in claim. Then it works both for UI (`HttpContext.User.IsInRole("Admin")`) and for `authorize` attribute (`[Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]`).

Startup.cs file:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{    
    services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>()                
      .AddEntityFrameworkStores<WandContext>();
    ///..... other code
}
```

During authentication, I add role to my claim.

```
var invalidLoginAttempt = false;
var user = await _userManager.FindByNameAsync(loginModel.Email);
if (user != null)
{
    var result = await _signInManager.CheckPasswordSignInAsync(user, loginModel.Password, lockoutOnFailure: true);

    if (result.Succeeded)
    {                                       
        var customClaims = new List<Claim>
        {
            new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, Role.Admin)
        };

        var claimsIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(customClaims, CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
        var claimsPrincipal = new ClaimsPrincipal(claimsIdentity);

        await _signInManager.Context.SignInAsync(IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme,
            claimsPrincipal, new AuthenticationProperties { IsPersistent = loginModel.RememberMe });

        return LocalRedirect(returnUrl);
    }
    else if (result.IsLockedOut)
        ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "This account has been locked out, please try again later.");
    else
        invalidLoginAttempt = true;
}
else
    invalidLoginAttempt = true;
```

Answer (score 1):

I got roles working by calling `JwtSecurityTokenHandler.DefaultInboundClaimTypeMap.Clear();` before `services.AddAuthentication` in `Startup.cs`.

I also added

```
services.AddScoped<IProfileService, ProfileService>();
```

and `ProfileService.cs` that looks like this to map roles to claims:

```
public sealed class ProfileService : IProfileService
{
    private readonly IUserClaimsPrincipalFactory<ApplicationUser> _userClaimsPrincipalFactory;
    private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userMgr;
    private readonly RoleManager<IdentityRole> _roleMgr;

    public ProfileService(
        UserManager<ApplicationUser> userMgr,
        RoleManager<IdentityRole> roleMgr,
        IUserClaimsPrincipalFactory<ApplicationUser> userClaimsPrincipalFactory)
    {
        _userMgr = userMgr;
        _roleMgr = roleMgr;
        _userClaimsPrincipalFactory = userClaimsPrincipalFactory;
    }

    public async Task GetProfileDataAsync(ProfileDataRequestContext context)
    {
        string sub = context.Subject.GetSubjectId();
        ApplicationUser user = await _userMgr.FindByIdAsync(sub);
        ClaimsPrincipal userClaims = await _userClaimsPrincipalFactory.CreateAsync(user);

        List<Claim> claims = userClaims.Claims.ToList();
        claims = claims.Where(claim => context.RequestedClaimTypes.Contains(claim.Type)).ToList();

        if (_userMgr.SupportsUserRole)
        {
            IList<string> roles = await _userMgr.GetRolesAsync(user);
            foreach (var roleName in roles)
            {
                claims.Add(new Claim(JwtClaimTypes.Role, roleName));
                if (_roleMgr.SupportsRoleClaims)
                {
                    IdentityRole role = await _roleMgr.FindByNameAsync(roleName);
                    if (role != null)
                    {
                        claims.AddRange(await _roleMgr.GetClaimsAsync(role));
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        context.IssuedClaims = claims;
    }

    public async Task IsActiveAsync(IsActiveContext context)
    {
        string sub = context.Subject.GetSubjectId();
        ApplicationUser user = await _userMgr.FindByIdAsync(sub);
        context.IsActive = user != null;
    }
}
```

Source:

https://ffimnsr.medium.com/adding-identity-roles-to-identity-server-4-in-net-core-3-1-d42b64ff6675