# How to use roles in .NET MVC Core

Tags: .net, identity, roles

I have tried for days now to implement roles in a MVC project. I have started a new project and chosen Authentication to "Individual user account". I added the [Authorize] to HomeControllers Indexpage and everything works. To add a role i included:

```
services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>().AddRoles<IdentityRole>().AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
```

to startup.cs ->ConfigureServices
and then added a call to following functions from startup->Configure

```
private async Task CreateRole(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
{
    var RoleManager = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<RoleManager<IdentityRole>>();
    IdentityResult roleResult;
    roleResult = await RoleManager.CreateAsync(new IdentityRole("Admin"));
}

private async Task SetUserAdmin(string username, IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
{
    var UserManager = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<UserManager<IdentityUser>>();
    IdentityUser user = await UserManager.FindByEmailAsync(username);
    await UserManager.AddToRoleAsync(user, "Admin");
}
```

this will create the role "Admin" and bind it to a specific user.
When i look at the table in the db via:

```
select * from AspNetRoles
select * from AspNetUsers
select * from AspNetUserRoles
```

The tables is populated and linked to eachother but when i use [Authorize(Roles="Admin")] error page 401 will appear, but when i read out the roles for the user via:

```
var roles = await UserManager.GetRolesAsync(await UserManager.FindByEmailAsync(username));
```

It will return the value "Admin".

What can be the problem?
Big thanks for any suggestions!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How did you add Identity in the startup file?
I think it's going wrong with `services.AddIdentity`.

I use:

```
services.AddIdentity<IndentityUser, IdentityRole>(options => options.Stores.MaxLengthForKeys = 128)
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
                .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

This is a known bug for .Net Core 2.1 [.net core identity 2.1 role authorize not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52526186/net-core-identity-2-1-role-authorize-not-working)

Should be solved in 2.2

Comment: Thanks for the reply, i have basically scaffolded in the identity and in services.AddDefaultIdentity added .AddRoles<IdentityRole>(). The database seems to be correct, but [Authorize(Roles="Admin")] brings me to 401 page, while [Authorize] works fine.

Comment: Which version of .Net Core are you using? Just for troubleshooting try services.AddIdentity<IdentityUser, IdentityRole>() instead of services.AddDefaultIdentity().AddRoles<IdentityRole>(). Have you specified the AddEntityFrameworkStores?

Comment: I am using .Net Core 2.1. The change from AddDefaultIdentity to AddIdentity fixed the problem with reacting to [Authorize(roles="Admin")], but now the program tries to find the loginpage at Account/Login instead of Identity/Account/Login. Plus that the register doesnt work due to the IEmailSender... I cant seem to find a walkthrough online to this problem, even though it surely must be a common thing to implement? Do you know where this can be found so i can understand whats happening?

Comment: Thought so, this is a known bug: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52526186/net-core-identity-2-1-role-authorize-not-working If it's possible I would suggest updating to .Net Core 2.2

Comment: Finally it works! Your link and C-Berber:s post fixed the problem. Big thanks for the help!