# i have created a role for a user in identity, but when i use it says not authorized

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, roles

i am using default identity provided by asp.netcore, i have made a role named admin and have also inserted related data in ASPNetUserRoles table,
and on my controller i wrote [Authorize(Roles = "Admin")], but still when i try to access that controller, it says, not authorized.
here are the following codes.

i have double checked that userid and roleid is correct

select id from AspNetUsers
id
58005002-d0d4-4db1-b0bb-5a474cca8013

select * from AspNetRoles
id name normalizedName ConcurrencyStamp
c4a56464-53f7-440c-b904-fbc7389ed00a    Admin   ADMIN   080dbb2c-789e-4e28-95fd-6bc73d8b199e

select * from AspNetUserRoles
UserId RoleId
58005002-d0d4-4db1-b0bb-5a474cca8013    c4a56464-53f7-440c-b904-fbc7389ed00a

[Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]
    public class AdminController : Controller
    {

```
    // GET: /<controller>/
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

i can access other controllers which are only authorized with no roles, but i am having problem with this.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add roles to your services in `Startup.cs` file

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>()
        .AddRoles<IdentityRole>();
}
```

Comment: i already have it
services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>().AddRoles<IdentityRole>()
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<DeadAliveDbContext>();

Answer (score 0):

From this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52526186/net-core-identity-2-1-role-authorize-not-working),try to register `RoleManager<IdentityRole>` like

```
services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>()
   .AddRoles<IdentityRole>()
   .AddRoleManager<RoleManager<IdentityRole>>()
   .AddDefaultUI(UIFramework.Bootstrap4)
   .AddEntityFrameworkStores<DeadAliveDbContext>();
```