# NET Core 3.1 - 403 when [Authorize(Roles = "Administrator")]

Tags: .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-3.0

I'm using Identity Server features, with NET Core 3.1.

What are the requirements in the database when having a role protecting a route?

E.g. `[Authorize(Roles = "Administrator")]`

1. I have a user created in `AspNetUsers` table.
2. I have a role created in `AspNetRoles` table. The value for name is `Administrator` and NormalizedName is `ADMINISTRATOR`.
3. I have a row in `AspNetUserRoles` table with the guid from User and Role.

When hitting this route, I'm getting `403 Forbidden`.

Am I missing something?

EDIT 1

The code I'm using add the role is 
`await userManager.AddToRoleAsync(user, "Administrator");`

EDIT 2

Here's the `Startup.cs` file.

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UI;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpsPolicy;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.ReactDevelopmentServer;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using SampleApp.Data;
using SampleApp.Models;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using SampleApp.Entities;
using AutoMapper;
using System;
using SampleApp.Services;
using SampleApp.Middlewares;

namespace SampleApp
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public IConfiguration _configuration { get; }

        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            _configuration = configuration ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(configuration));

        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddScoped<ISampleAppRepository, SampleAppRepository>();

            var emailConfig = _configuration
                .GetSection("EmailConfiguration")
                .Get<EmailConfiguration>();

            services.AddSingleton(emailConfig);

            services.AddTransient<IPasswordHasher<User>, PasswordHasher<User>>();

            services.AddScoped<IShippingEmailSender, ShippingEmailSender>();

            services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
            {
                options.UseSqlServer(_configuration["connectionStrings:databaseConnectionString"]);
            });

            services.AddDefaultIdentity<User>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
                .AddRoles<IdentityRole>()
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();

            services.AddIdentityServer()
                .AddApiAuthorization<User, ApplicationDbContext>();

            services.AddAuthentication()
                .AddIdentityServerJwt();

            services.AddControllersWithViews(setupAction =>
            {
                setupAction.ReturnHttpNotAcceptable = true;

            }).AddXmlDataContractSerializerFormatters();

            services.AddRazorPages();

            // In production, the React files will be served from this directory
            services.AddSpaStaticFiles(configuration =>
            {
                configuration.RootPath = "ClientApp/build";
            });

            services.AddMvc();

            services.AddAutoMapper(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies());
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
                app.UseDatabaseErrorPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
                // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                app.UseHsts();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseSpaStaticFiles();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseMiddleware<TenantDetectionMiddleware>();

            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseIdentityServer();
            app.UseAuthorization();
            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
                endpoints.MapRazorPages();
            });

            app.UseSpa(spa =>
            {
                spa.Options.SourcePath = "ClientApp";

                if (env.IsDevelopment())
                {
                    spa.UseReactDevelopmentServer(npmScript: "start");
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you assigned the Role to the User

Comment: I'm using the `User Manager` class and the method `AddToRoleAsync`. That added the row in `AspNetUserRoles` table.

Comment: What do you mean by remove roles? Remove the row in `AspNetUserRoles` table?

Comment: when you remove the Roles Attribute from your controller and just use [Authorize], can you access.

Comment: Yes, 200 response.

Comment: This means issue is with your User registration code and add to Role method, share those codes here

Comment: I just did to the question.

Comment: Based on the existing description and very few code snippets, it‘s a bit difficult to find the cause of the problem.Could you share the configuration in `Startup.cs`or the relevant code that can reproduce the issue?

Comment: Just added that!

Comment: Stale cookie/claims? Did you logout and back in again?

Comment: I have tried that many times. Logout and login again. The API call from React still would return 403 when I changed it from `[Authorize]` to `[Authorize(Roles = "Administrator")]`

Comment: Not a solution, but a way to diagnose the problem: logout and login, and, on a page, dump all the claims of the current user. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.claims.claimsprincipal.claims.

Comment: Are you making the call from JavaScript? If so, are you sure that the cookie is being passed along?

Comment: @RicardoPeres database wise, should it be a relationship between a Claim and a User? I thought that since we were talking roles, there's no need for that.

Comment: No, there shouldn't... just wondering.

Comment: But there should be a relation between a role assigned to a user and a claim!

Comment: @RicardoPeres would it be ok to get into a chat with you?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I was missing this.

```
services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme;
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme;
    options.DefaultSignInScheme = IdentityConstants.ExternalScheme;
});
```

Thanks to this answer!
https://stackoverflow.com/a/56473365/779975

Comment: If you find the answer yourself, you can accept it. Good luck

Comment: Thanks! @RamilAliyev